# Solving system of ODE with elimination method for $x'-2x+y'=0$ and $x'-x+y'-y=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that a system of ODE is comprised of
$$x'-2x+y'=0$$
$$x'-x+y'-y=0$$

Naturally, I'll reformat this into the following:

$$(1) \ \ \ (D-2)x+(D)y=0$$
$$(2) \ \ \ (D-1)x+(D-1)y=0$$

And when I eliminate the y, I get $(-2D+2)x=0$ and solving for $D$ gets $D=1$ so one of my general solution is $x(t)=c_1e^x$ but this is where the problem happens. Say I plug that solution into $(1)$, then we'd get $-c_1e^x+(D)y=0$. How am I supposed to find the solution on the Y side? Or is there a better way of solving for this ODE?

Comment: You should first solve the system by eliminating either x' or y' from the equation. If you do that you get a trivial equation with the solution you mentioned. Working with the differential operators like you did makes it more complicated.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the System correctly ? Because at first glance you can deduce that $y=x$

Answer (score 1):

$$x'-2x+y'=0$$
$$x'-x+y'-y=0$$
Substract both DE:
$$-2x+x+y=0$$
$$\implies y=x$$
Substitute this in the first DE and solve.
$$x'-2x+y'=0$$
$$x'-2x+x'=0$$
$$x'-x=0$$
This is easy to solve then deduce $y$ since $y=x$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Apply $D-1$ to the top and $D-2$ to the bottom equations respectively and subtract the new top equation to the new bottom equation to get a ODE equation only $y$ and solve for $y$, then come back to solve for $x$ using linear first order ODE standard.